# When using db.someDb.update([]), how do you $set an array in Mongodb without creating an object?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, set, aggregate

I've seen similar questions to update and set, but none seem to tackle what I'm talking about. Let's say you have antsDb with the below docs

```
{ "name": "ant1", "antId": 1, "colId": "colony1" }
{ "name": "ant2", "antId": 2, "colId": "colony1" }
{ "name": "ant3", "antId": 3, "colId": "colony2" }
```

and you have colonyDb with

```
{ "colId": "colony1", "jobsArray": ["findFood", "workHard", "carryFood", "feedQueen"] }
{ "colId": "colony2", "jobsArray": ["childCare", "cutLeaves", "feedQueen"] }
```

I want to update every ant so that they have the jobsArray for their respective colony. But I don't want to create an object when I set the jobsArray for the ants. I thought I could just put

```
db.colonyDb.aggregate([]).forEach(function(col) {
   db.antsDb.update([
      {
         "colId": col.colId
      },
      {
         $set: {
            "myAntJobs": col.jobsArray
         }
      }
   ])
})
```

and that would set an array called myAntJobs on each matching ant document where it doesn't exist, resulting in

```
{ "name": "ant1", "antId": 1, "colId": "colony1", "myAntJobs": ["findFood", "workHard", "carryFood", "feedQueen"] }
{ "name": "ant2", "antId": 2, "colId": "colony1", "myAntJobs": ["findFood", "workHard", "carryFood", "feedQueen"] }
{ "name": "ant3", "antId": 3, "colId": "colony2", "myAntJobs": ["childCare", "cutLeaves", "feedQueen"] }
```

but I get **E QUERY    [js] Error: need an object** instead. I'm guessing it wants me to put something like:

```
$set: {
   "myAntJobs": {
      "myJobs": col.jobsArray
   }
}
```

Won't this make all of the arrays on the ants into objects with one field? Or am I thinking of this the wrong way...
The biggest issue is I don't really have a space for testing (although I put so much effort into making this question, I could probably use what I just typed out lol).

Can someone functionally explain how the $set works in this context? Also if you know of a better way to add an array to resultant docs in a forEach more effectively, please tell me. But I'd like to understand $set in this context first and foremost.

Comment: `db.antsDb.update([...]` - the _brackets_ aren't part of the syntax; see [db.collection.update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).

Comment: @prasad_ ah thanks for that. I altered that and still am getting an issue where it's not adding the new field still for some reason.

Comment: Your update's [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) should work fine, I think.